# Licensing ArcGIS Enterprise when scaling in cloud environment

Tags: license, amazon-web-services, arcgis-enterprise

Esri's ArcGIS Enterprise licenses are for use on machines with "up to 4 cores".  I understand that in cloud environments (such as AWS) that available machines have an equivalent number of physical cores associated with them (breakdown here https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/physicalcores/).

How would dynamic scaling of computing resources work in a scenario where resources need to be scaled beyond the 4 cores that are licensed?

For example, would two ArcGIS Enterprise licenses need to be purchased if an organization needs to intermittently scale up to the equivalent of an 8 core machine in an AWS environment?

Comment: This question is best asked of Inside Sales in your local Esri or distributor office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your option would be appear to purchase additional license based on ESRI's documentation here [Licensing ArcGIS Enterprise
Deployments in Virtualized
and Cloud Environments](https://www.esri.com/content/dam/esrisites/en-us/media/whitepaper/licensing-arcgis-enterprise-deployments-in-virtualized-and-cloud-environments.pdf)

> The ArcGIS Server component of ArcGIS Enterprise is licensed by CPU cores. Cores
> are part of the computer’s CPU (Central Processing Unit) that determines the number
> of instructions that can be processed at a given time. A 4-core processor can handle
> four sets of instructions at once. Many modern CPUs further support a technology
> known as hyper-threading that allows a single core to run multiple concurrent sets of
> instructions. Hyper-threads do not count towards the licensed cores.
> Licensed cores can be counted by physical cores or virtual cores, whichever is more
> advantageous to you. The minimum purchase for ArcGIS Enterprise is an “up-to-4
> core” license* which can be installed on a two or four core machine. If your machine
> has more than 4 cores (physical or virtual), you can purchase additional cores, or
> virtualize the machine so that the 4-core license of ArcGIS Enterprise is only installed
> on 4 (virtual) cores and thereby satisfies the license requirement.
> **If a 4-core license is installed on an 8-core physical machine without virtualization,
> then ArcGIS Enterprise will use all 8 cores and would be in violation of the license
> agreement until you purchase a license for the four “additional cores”.**